# Flash dynamic stage size control

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Did the stage can be changed dynamically in runtime? Means if the initial size is 400X300 and I want to change the size of the swf stage from html by 600x600?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the size of the stage from SWF e.g. by `stage.stageWidth = 600;` but you can tell containing HTML page to change width/height properties of embedded SWF then in your SWF you can respond to stage size change e.g.

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResized, false, 0, true);
```

and update layout from there

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of the swf however you want in HTML. However, by default it will only *scale* the content, i.e., your code isn't aware of the external size of the swf.

If you set the `Stage.scaleMode` to `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE` and the `Stage.align` property to `StageAlign.TOP_LEFT`, the stage will not scale but instead be set to the actual available dimensions.